# Can't run Hyperloop project

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-hyperloop, appc-hyperloop, hyperloop

I've downloaded the latest SDK from master as explained here: http://builds.appcelerator.com/#master

I've also downloaded the latest Hyperloop from here http://labs.appcelerator.com/project/55f74a9f421c44837717716b/Hyperloop-Module and followed the instructions in the PDF file.

I created a new Alloy project, in `tiapp.xml` I've created the `plugin` and `module` and ran my empty project. it didn't seem to complete compilation. it is stuck on:

```
[INFO] :   Alloy compiler completed successfully
[WARN] :   Hyperloop is currently available in Beta and should not be used for production applications.
[INFO] :   Starting Hyperloop assembly
[INFO] :   Skipping Hyperloop compile, no usage found ...
```

I have also tried downloading the Hyperloop examples project. Output was a little different there - but still did not complete compilation. Here's the output:

```
[INFO] :   Alloy compiler completed successfully
[WARN] :   Hyperloop is currently available in Beta and should not be used for production applications.
[INFO] :   Starting Hyperloop assembly
[INFO] :   [Hyperloop] Building CocoaPods dependencies
[WARN] :   The iOS framework "javax.crypto.KeyGenerator" could not be found. Are you trying to use "JavaScriptCore" or "JBChartView" instead? (android/alloy/controllers/touchid.js)
[WARN] :   The iOS framework "javax.crypto.Cipher" could not be found. Are you trying to use "JavaScriptCore" or "JBChartView" instead? (android/alloy/controllers/touchid.js)
```

The instruction PDF mentioned that I need to download SDK 5.2.0 - but it doesn't exists in builds - so I downloaded 6.0.0.xxxxxxx

How can I make Hyperloop run?

Answer (score 0):

Judging by..

```
[WARN] :   The iOS framework "javax.crypto.KeyGenerator" could not be found. Are you trying to use "JavaScriptCore" or "JBChartView" instead? (android/alloy/controllers/touchid.js)
[WARN] :   The iOS framework "javax.crypto.Cipher" could not be found. Are you trying to use "JavaScriptCore" or "JBChartView" instead? (android/alloy/controllers/touchid.js)
```

it looks like you compile for iOS, while HL still tries to parse the Android specific controllers - which it shouldn't. This bug has already been reported at the Appcelerator JIRA and can be tracked via:

https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/AC-563

To download a 5_2_x nightly you could use `appc ti sdk install -b 5_2_x`.

Comment: After downloading 5_2_x compilation completed and app launched on device - but now I get the red screen saying "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Ti.Stream.pump') at app.js (line 231)"

Comment: on a new project (not the examples) it's still stuck on "Skipping Hyperloop compile, no usage found ..."

Comment: Ok, so it seems like there's a bug where if the hyperloop compiler doesn't find anything to do it says it skips but in fact it hangs (probably doesn't call a callback). You could easily find out by adding a require for some kind of native API. To report a bug with Appcelerator go to https://jira.appcelerator.org

Comment: As for `Ti.Stream.pump`, that's something LiveView uses. Do you have that enabled perhaps?

Comment: @developer82 I've found an Appcelerator JIRA ticket for the original issue you had. I ran into it myself with the latest 5_2_X as well: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/AC-563

Comment: No. just ran the example project as is and got `Ti.Stream.pump` message

Comment: I can't understand the difference between the example project and a newly created project that doesn't pass compilation. I even tried coping `tiapp.xml` entirely from one to another and the module and pluging from the example project - nothing.

Comment: @developer82 could you create a new question for the `Ti.Stream.pump` problem so that we can close this one which has been reproduced and reported as bug?

Comment: Hi, any idea why I can't run Hyperloop on a new project? would be happy to send you any log you need...

Comment: That's where you get the `Ti.Stream.pump` error with right? On a new project. Could you create a separate question for that so we don't mix up that error with the one that started this question?

Comment: No. I get `Ti.Stream.pump` on the example project. New project doesn't pass compilation - it stops at `[INFO] :   Starting Hyperloop assembly`

Comment: Anyway, it's a different error. If you could create a new question for that, then we'll continue there OK?

Comment: posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34999704/hyperloop-compilation-error

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed with Titanium SDK 5.4.0.GA and Hyperloop 1.2.0.