# Hyperloop compilation error

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-hyperloop, appc-hyperloop, hyperloop

I've written before about a problem running [Hyperloop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34817022/cant-run-hyperloop-project) project.
 If run a newly created project to witch I added Hyperloop from Appcelerator Studio it seems like compilation is stuck on:

```
[INFO]  Starting Hyperloop assembly
[INFO]  Skipping Hyperloop compile, no usage found ...
```

So what I did now is to run it from command line using:

```
HyperloopApp ophir$ appc run -p ios
```

And right after `Skipping Hyperloop compile, no usage found ...` I get the following error messages:

```
/Users/ophir/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/HyperloopApp/plugins/hyperloop/hooks/ios/hyperloop.js:581
        return callback();
         ^
ReferenceError: callback is not defined
    at HyperloopiOSBuilder.copyHyperloopJSFiles (/Users/ophir/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/HyperloopApp/plugins/hyperloop/hooks/ios/hyperloop.js:581:10)
    at /Users/ophir/.appcelerator/install/5.1.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/node-appc/lib/async.js:64:45
    at /Users/ophir/.appcelerator/install/5.1.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:689:13
    at iterate (/Users/ophir/.appcelerator/install/5.1.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:265:13)
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:433:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:362:13)
---------------------------------------------
    at /Users/ophir/.appcelerator/install/5.1.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:275:35
    at /Users/ophir/.appcelerator/install/5.1.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:44:16
    at /Users/ophir/.appcelerator/install/5.1.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:694:17
    at /Users/ophir/.appcelerator/install/5.1.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:173:37
    at HyperloopiOSBuilder.generateStubs (/Users/ophir/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/HyperloopApp/plugins/hyperloop/hooks/ios/hyperloop.js:556:10)
    at /Users/ophir/.appcelerator/install/5.1.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:689:13
    at iterate (/Users/ophir/.appcelerator/install/5.1.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:265:13)
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:433:9)
---------------------------------------------
    at /Users/ophir/.appcelerator/install/5.1.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:275:35
    at /Users/ophir/.appcelerator/install/5.1.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:44:16
    at /Users/ophir/.appcelerator/install/5.1.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:694:17
    at /Users/ophir/.appcelerator/install/5.1.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:173:37
    at /Users/ophir/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/HyperloopApp/plugins/hyperloop/node_modules/hyperloop-metabase/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:52:16
    at Object.async.forEachOf.async.eachOf (/Users/ophir/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/HyperloopApp/plugins/hyperloop/node_modules/hyperloop-metabase/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:236:30)
    at Object.async.forEach.async.each (/Users/ophir/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/HyperloopApp/plugins/hyperloop/node_modules/hyperloop-metabase/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:209:22)
    at Object.compileResources (/Users/ophir/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/HyperloopApp/plugins/hyperloop/node_modules/hyperloop-metabase/lib/metabase.js:440:8)
    at HyperloopiOSBuilder.compileResources (/Users/ophir/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/HyperloopApp/plugins/hyperloop/hooks/ios/hyperloop.js:547:14)
---------------------------------------------
    at /Users/ophir/.appcelerator/install/5.1.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:275:35
    at /Users/ophir/.appcelerator/install/5.1.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:44:16
    at /Users/ophir/.appcelerator/install/5.1.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:694:17
    at /Users/ophir/.appcelerator/install/5.1.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:173:37
    at /Users/ophir/.appcelerator/install/5.1.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/node-appc/lib/async.js:64:51
    at /Users/ophir/.appcelerator/install/5.1.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:689:13
    at iterate (/Users/ophir/.appcelerator/install/5.1.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:265:13)
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:433:9)
---------------------------------------------
    at /Users/ophir/.appcelerator/install/5.1.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:275:35
    at /Users/ophir/.appcelerator/install/5.1.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:44:16
    at /Users/ophir/.appcelerator/install/5.1.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:694:17
    at /Users/ophir/.appcelerator/install/5.1.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:173:37
    at HyperloopiOSBuilder.generateSourceFiles (/Users/ophir/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/HyperloopApp/plugins/hyperloop/hooks/ios/hyperloop.js:467:10)
    at /Users/ophir/.appcelerator/install/5.1.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:689:13
    at iterate (/Users/ophir/.appcelerator/install/5.1.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:265:13)
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:433:9)
---------------------------------------------
    at /Users/ophir/.appcelerator/install/5.1.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:275:35
    at /Users/ophir/.appcelerator/install/5.1.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:44:16
    at /Users/ophir/.appcelerator/install/5.1.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:694:17
    at /Users/ophir/.appcelerator/install/5.1.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:173:37
    at HyperloopiOSBuilder.<anonymous> (/Users/ophir/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/HyperloopApp/plugins/hyperloop/hooks/ios/hyperloop.js:454:4)
    at /Users/ophir/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/HyperloopApp/plugins/hyperloop/node_modules/hyperloop-metabase/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:52:16
    at replenish (/Users/ophir/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/HyperloopApp/plugins/hyperloop/node_modules/hyperloop-metabase/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:314:29)
    at /Users/ophir/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/HyperloopApp/plugins/hyperloop/node_modules/hyperloop-metabase/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:326:29
    at /Users/ophir/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/HyperloopApp/plugins/hyperloop/node_modules/hyperloop-metabase/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:44:16
---------------------------------------------
    at /Users/ophir/.appcelerator/install/5.1.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:275:35
    at /Users/ophir/.appcelerator/install/5.1.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:44:16
    at /Users/ophir/.appcelerator/install/5.1.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:694:17
    at /Users/ophir/.appcelerator/install/5.1.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:173:37
    at HyperloopiOSBuilder.processThirdPartyFrameworks (/Users/ophir/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/HyperloopApp/plugins/hyperloop/hooks/ios/hyperloop.js:236:10)
    at /Users/ophir/.appcelerator/install/5.1.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:689:13
    at iterate (/Users/ophir/.appcelerator/install/5.1.0/pa2016-01-25T18:27:44.759Z | ERROR  | ti run exited with error code 1
```

How can I make Hyperloop run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution. apparently it seems to be a permission problem - even if the message isn't so. since I had the following line:

```
[INFO]  Skipping Hyperloop compile, no usage found ...
```

I decided to add a minimal Hyperloop code inside the project:

```
var UIView = require('UIKit/UIView');
```

Then when I ran again I got a different error message starting with:

```
Error: spawn EACCES
```

This is something I already know to be permission issues - and it makes sense since the Hyperloop module was downloaded from the internet.

fixup was easy, just run

```
sudo chmod -R a+rwx /appfolder
```

everything compiles.

Comment: Thanks for finding these bugs. I didn't run into the EACCES error, but I did reproduce, report and fix the "no usage found" one: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-20274

Comment: I'm still getting this issue. I tried using 6.0.0.v20160218102417  and 5.2.0.v20160216202526   appc -v 5.2.0-265  ti -v 5.0.6

Comment: @Kosso did you try running from CLI and not from Studio? if so, what error are you getting?

Comment: I tried both CLI and Studio.  Same error as above.  Following the guide from here : http://labs.appcelerator.com/project/55f74a9f421c44837717716b/Hyperloop-Module

Comment: Also, running the Example app gives me the same error reported here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34817022/cant-run-hyperloop-project

Comment: @developer82 No. But I did try the chmod cmd above too.  See the log here : https://gist.github.com/kosso/51901174586d9f61b735

Comment: @developer82 Well now I've got it to compile! I trashed the old build folders. /sigh/

Comment: @developer82  Interestingly, I added `var UIView = require('UIKit/UIView');` as you had, but after running appc, it rewrites this in my .js file as `var UIView = require('hyperloop/uikit/uiview');`  - then the next run doesn't work.

Comment: @Kosso what error messages are you getting? can you open a new question with more detailed and log information?

Comment: @developer82 a link to log is in previous comment. btw: Which exact combination of CLI / SDK / etc versions have you found that work to compile a simple hyperloop test app?  I've tried so many different versions.  Much appreciated.